# Вырезка содержимого между фигурными скобками

Tags: регулярные-выражения, bash

Имеется `network={ ssid="имя" psk="ключ" }`

Необходимо вырезать регуляркой на bash и оставить только содержимое внутри.
Ну и 2 пробела которые иду после `{` и перед `}`

Comment: А вопрос то где. Вопроса не вижу, а вижу задание.

Comment: Я не силен в регулярках.

Comment: Ну так хотя бы покажите код, который есть, чтобы воспроизвести и протестировать.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "network={ ssid=\"имя\" psk=\"ключ\" }" | sed 's/[^{]*{\([^}]*\)}.*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

можно реализовать требуемое и собственными средствами программы *bash*, без привлечения сторонних программ (типа *sed*, *awk*, *tr* и т.п.).

итак, есть строка:

```
$ v='network={ ssid="имя" psk="ключ" }'
```

1. вывести всё после символа `{`:

   ```
   $ echo ${v#*{}
   ssid="имя" psk="ключ" }
   ```
2. вывести всё до сивола `}`:

   ```
   $ echo ${v%\}*}
   network={ ssid="имя" psk="ключ"
   ```
3. для «совмещения» этих двух действий потребуется использовать либо промежуточную переменную, либо ту же самую, но её содержимое при этом будет изменено:

   1. промежуточная переменная:

      ```
      $ v1=${v#*{}; echo ${v1%\}*}
      ssid="имя" psk="ключ"
      ```
   2. та же самая переменная:

      ```
      $ v=${v#*{}; echo ${v%\}*}
      ssid="имя" psk="ключ"
      ```
4. убрать же все начальные, конечные и дублирующиеся внутри строки пробелы можно, например, с помощью встроенной команды `echo`:

   ```
   $ v2='  ssid="имя"   psk="ключ" '
   $ v3=$(echo $v2)
   $ echo $v3
   ssid="имя" psk="ключ"
   ```

   контрольная проверка на отсутствие начальных/конечных пробелов:

   ```
   $ echo "'$v3'"
   'ssid="имя" psk="ключ"'
   ```
5. **подведём итог**:

   ```
   $ v='network={ ssid="имя" psk="ключ" }'
   $ v1=${v#*{}; v1=$(echo ${v1%\}*})
   ```

   контрольная проверка:

   ```
   $ echo "'$v1'"
   'ssid="имя" psk="ключ"'
   ```